# Job offer was rescinded just days before starting. How should I proceed?

Tags: job-offer, notice-period

I currently work at Company A (media/entertainment) and recently interviewed at and accepted an offer at Company B (agriculture).

As of today, I was on my last couple of days at Company A, after giving them 4 weeks notice. I spoke with my manager at length when giving notice, about how I was no longer happy working in media/entertainment and was looking for a change of industry and to improve my mental health. He was very supportive and understood my decision.

Over the last 4 weeks, I've been filling out paper work for Company B and they've already sent me a company laptop and other home office equipment. Both positions are remote.

Today, Company B calls to tell me that due to business/financial reasons they had to rescind my offer. I was set to start working there in just 3 days. They told me it had nothing to do with me personally (background check passed, interviewers gave glowing reviews, etc.) and that if the situation changes, I would be among the first to be hired. There's no timeline of that, however.

With intense humiliation and awkwardness I had a call with my manager at Company A and let him know. He said he needs to talk to HR to see what can be done. He said they would be glad to keep me if they could, but did bring up a (completely valid) question about my motivation to keep working in media/entertainment. He said he'd talk to me soon after consulting HR.

In the mean time, I've started applying to some jobs to prepare for a possible worst case scenario. But my manager brings up a good point. I don't want to work at Company A in the first place, but it is better than being unemployed. I've clearly shown that I'm a "flight risk".

Do I go back to Company A long term? Should I ask for just an extension of my notice period? Or should I just charge ahead applying to new jobs?

I saw this [related question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/156560/my-current-company-agreed-to-take-me-back-after-i-had-another-offer-rescinded-i), but the crucial difference with me is that the labor market is very different than it was two years ago (much more in favor of employees). Financially, I'm okay for now. I have a year's worth of savings and my wife will be starting working soon now also.

This is in the Eastern US.

Comment: On this Stackexchange, we can't make those decisions for you. But personally, I don't see what the problem is. You have money. The market is good. Plus, it's unlikely that company A hires you back anyway unless they want you to finish up a project or something (and even if they do hire you back, it will only be temporary, they'll ditch you as soon as they can). Also, you mention your mental health, if you need a break for your mental health, you should take it.

Comment: How much paper work for Company B did you complete? It's possible that, technically, you were hired and then laid off. - If you don't find something soon, maybe you can apply for unemployment benefits.

Comment: We always tell people to wait until they have a contract or at east a signed offer in hand before giving notice -- but evidently in the U.S. even this is not a guarantee of continued employment.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Of course, you can also get fired in the first week depending on what is stated in the contract. So a signed contract doesn't mean much with respect to job security. However, you are right, the OP may be able to get unemployment benefits.

Comment: OP, maybe it doesn't mean much to you, but you are in a lot better position than a lot of people that suddenly lose their job. If you have a years worth of savings, that's great. Good luck!

Comment: I voted to "Leave Open" because the situation is not the OP's fault. It should be company B's. To the Close voters, can you be sure you will never bump into this situation that the OP encountered?

Comment: @Nobody Who caused the situation should have no bearing on if it should be closed or not.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri That is not only in the US though, for example in The Netherlands, a 1 - 2 month probation period is normal (1 month is the legal maximum for a contract period of 6 months or more and less than 2 years, and 2 the legal maximum for contract periods of more than 2 years, and only for the first contract). A contract can be ended by either party immediately without reason during that probation period.

Comment: This is the exact reason why you keep it short and sweet when you resign and not get into the truth of why you are leaving. Simply telling your manager that you found a new opportunity is all you need to say. Telling them how you dislike the company, industry, job, people, etc. can come back to burn you in the end and your manager is correct to give pause in keeping you on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- You "don't want to work at Company A in the first place".
- You want to improve mental health.
- You don't have immediate financial problems.
- You have a chance of getting a better job within few months.

Then it is better that you "just charge ahead applying to new jobs".

But if manager of company A agrees to keep you employed temporarily in spite of being a "flight risk" (may be he doesn't have a new employee ready and trained enough to do the job), then go back to company A telling them that you applying for new jobs.

Comment: In fact querent's principal value to company A may be to train his replacement.

Answer (score 1):

First resurrect any efforts towards finding a new job. I always give the advice to keep at least some forward movement on other applications until your first day of work. Ramp up that search.

If you do decide to stay with Company A, realize your hold on that job maybe extremely weak. They know you wanted to leave. You will be the first to be cut if they need to save money. They may see your rehiring as a way to get a few more weeks of post-notice period time from you.

Never tell the company you are leaving more than you legally have to about the new job or the reason for leaving. Giving them a list of reasons doesn't help you. In this case it may have even hurt your ability to rejoin the company.

The next few weeks if you stay with company A your hidden agenda it to do things that increase your likelihood of extending your position another week.

As to stay or go. Only you can make that decision.